# Is there a way to force scikit MLP to have one output node for binary classification?

Tags: logistic, neural-networks

A binary classification problem:

I need to build an MLP network with 2 input nodes + bias, 2 hidden layer nodes + bias, 1 output node. The output node predicts 0 if output node returns a value less than 0.5, and 1 otherwise.

By default, the MLP creates two output nodes.